# How do I check if I can access the image url before displaying it? Flutter

Tags: flutter, image

I have a list of pictures provided through an url.

Two of them are easily accessible, one of them is 403 forbidden.

When I try to display all of them in a listview, the 403 displays an exception but still occupies an empty space in the listview, so I've tried Image.network and the errorBuilder, it just provides me with an alternative widget, but for my scenario, when an image is 403, I don't want it on the list at all, I don't want any alternative, I want the list size to be reduced by 1.

So I tried making a new list of strings that would house all the working urls by accessing all the images through a try/catch block and only adding those that didn't throw an exception. But the problem is that Image.network and NetworkImage don't catch exceptions.

So how do I make a list of working url images out of a list of potentially forbidden url images?

One of the things I've tried is making a function that would return an Image widget if it's correct and Text widget if it's caught by the errorbuilder, and then if the return type is an Image widget, I add the image to the list of working urls.

```
Widget imageExists(String url) {
    try {
      return Image.network(
        url,
        errorBuilder: (context, error, stackTrace) {
          return const Text("It's not working");
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return const SizedBox();
    }
  }
```

But the return type is always Image because it's not actually trying to access the image at the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for make a list of "ok url images" use the packeg http

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

the following function receives a list of urls and returns a list of urls working

```
Future<List<String>> filterValidImages(List<String> urls) async {
  var validUrls = <String>[];
  
  for (var url in urls) {
    final response = await http.head(Uri.parse(url));
    
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      validUrls.add(url);
    }
  }
  
  return validUrls;
}
```

Comment: This definitely works, and thank you for the idea, but doing this for every picture that I get from an API is veryyyy slow. I wish there was a way in Flutter to check it without calling http get for every picture